# R Shiny tooltip css not being applied

Tags: css, r, shiny, tooltip

I am trying to add tooltips to an R Shiny app. I am using bsplus to implement this rather than shinyBS because of apparent conflicts with the package shinyWidgets.

I find I am unable to style my tooltips (which are absolutely tiny). Everything I find relates to people using shinyBS - but those solutions won't work when using bsplus.

A simple reprex provided below. Can anyone tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong in terms of styling the tooltips?

Thanks!

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)

ui <-

  fluidPage(
    bsplus::use_bs_tooltip(),

    tags$style(HTML(".tooltip .tooltiptext { visibility: hidden; background-color: blue; }
                    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext { visibility: visible; }")),

    sidebarLayout(

      sidebarPanel(

        numericInput(inputId = "id_num", label = "Test numeric input", value = 0.5, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.05) %>%
          bs_embed_tooltip("My tooltip text", delay = "dseconds(0)", placement = "right")

      ),

      mainPanel()
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add `bsplus::use_bs_tooltip()` in the UI, add this inside your `fluidpage`

**Update**

That is your system or browser problem, I have no error running the code above.
[image]

Comment: Good catch - yes I have. However this doesn't help with the css not applying...

Comment: I don't believe it is - the tooltip there isn't blue like is specified in the css

Comment: Because you have the wrong CSS selector, need to be ".tooltip .tooltip-inner"